# An isomorphism that takes Z12 (integers modulo 12 under addition) to Z13* (integers modulo 13 under multiplication)

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I'm having a hard time finding an isomorphism that takes the integers in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ (those integers modulo 12 under addition) to the integers in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^{*}$ (those integers modulo 13 that are relatively prime to 13 under multiplication)

The hint says to start with $\phi(1)$, where $\phi$ is the isomorphism, and try various $\phi(1)$ until that works.

Attempt:
I've started off by trying to work out what exactly the problem is asking.

If I have $7+9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ that's equal to 4. So what does that mean for $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$? $7 \cdot 9=11$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^{*}$. So do I want something that takes 4 to 11 if that was the case?

Comment: Hint: The multiplicative group of any finite field is a cyclic group.

Comment: You will find that $n$ goes to $2^n$ (modulo $13$) works.

Comment: @AndréNicolas True, but that's a little cryptic, no? :) Might you explain how you found that $2$ works?

Comment: Indeed cryptic. For OP, if we will map $1$ to $a$, we will be forced to map $n$ to $a^n$. I needed an $a$ such that $a^1,a^2,a^3, a^{12}$ are distinct modulo $13$. Happen to know $2$ works. If one doesn't, trial and error will do it, and prsumably we will start with $a=2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two groups are both cyclic, which means that if there is an isomorphism it has to be a homomorphism that sends one generator to another.

Finding a generator in the former group is pretty simple: $1$ will do the trick.

The question now is: What is a generator in the latter group?

Can you take the problem from here?

---

Now that the problem has been solved, it might be interesting to note how you can move between these two groups using our isomorphism to solve some problems from number theory.

For example: What is $2^{25}$ mod $13$?

**Answer:** Using our isomorphism, we can send this back to $(\mathbb{Z}_{12}, +)$, where it is $25$ mod $12$, which is the same as $1$ mod $12$. We can now send this back where it came from, where it is $2^1$ mod $13$.

And there you have it: $2^{25}$ mod $13$ $\equiv$ $2$ mod $13$.

There are other (even simpler) ways to tackle this example, but the approach above might give you an idea about how Group Theory and Number Theory intersect; an early and important result one comes across in a first course on Abstract Algebra is often Fermat's Little Theorem, which is quite easily proved using ideas from Group Theory (namely, Lagrange's Theorem).

Comment: I think my problem is that I have not learned about generators yet when seeing this question. However, Andre's response makes sense to me. So I'm not sure which approach is the one I should be using or if they both lead up to the same thing. It may be that I am trying to answer this problem early before learning what generators are.

Comment: A finite group is called "cyclic" if you can take one element and get the whole group by repeatedly multiplying it with itself. For example, in your first group, you can start with $1$ and then consider: $1$, $1+1$, $1+1+1$, and so forth; eventually you will get the entire group. Andre notes that you can get the latter group by using: $2$, $2*2$, $2*2*2$, and so forth. In other words, $1$ is a generator for the former group, and $2$ for the latter, which means an isomorphism can send $1$ to $2$. Since it's a homomorphism, we also have $1+1$ sent to $2*2 = 4$, etc.

Comment: This suggests the isomorphism $\phi$ to be of the form $\phi(1) = 2$, $\phi(2) = 4$, and, more generally, $\phi(n) = 2^n$.

Comment: That makes much more sense now, but just to be clear the generator is what brings you from one group to the other. So to go from Z13* to Z12 the generator is 1, to go to Z12 to Z13* the generator is 2 because of what you wrote about 1+1,1+1+1, etc. and 2,2*2,2*2*2,etc. Thank you, I think this clears up a lot for me.

Comment: A group $G$ has generator $a$ if $G = \{a^n | n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. The generator is a single element: in (Z_12, +) one of the generators is 1. (You could check and see that 11 also works as a generator - in fact, whenever you have a generator, its inverse will be a generator, too!) In your latter group, 2 is a generator; but there are others! (For example, find the inverse of 2 in this group...)

Comment: In this group, the inverse of 2 would be 7 because 2*7=1 in modulo13. I also just checked 7^n(modulo 13) to confirm that it works as well.